# Prove that the trigonometric function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, continuity

> In my assignment I have to prove that the following function is uniformly continuous in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$:
>
> $$f(x)=\frac {1-\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Here is my suggestion for solution. Please let me know if I'm wrong somewhere:

I have to prove that if $|x_1-x_2|<\delta $ then  $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$:

$$\left|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\right|=\left|\frac {1-\sin x_1}{\cos x_1}-\frac {1-\sin x_2}{\cos x_2}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-\frac{\sin x_1}{\cos x_1}-\frac{1}{\cos x_2}+\frac{\sin x_2}{\cos x_2}\right|$$

Since |$\sin x|\le 1$ we can write the following, since the following term is bigger:

$$=\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-\frac{\sin x_1}{\cos x_1}-\frac{1}{\cos x_2}+\frac{1}{\cos x_2}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-\frac{\sin x_1}{\cos x_1}\right|$$

Since $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\tan x$:

$$=\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-\tan x_1\right|$$
Now since the interval which the function is the defined in this particular question is $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $\tan x_1>0$. Therefore, if we write the following term, we'll make it bigger:

$$=\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-\tan x_1\right|<\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-0\right|$$

Now we will choose $\delta=\frac{\cos x_1}{\epsilon}$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{\cos x_1}-0\right|<\frac{\cos x_1}{\epsilon}$$

Divide by $\cos x_1$ which is positive in the open interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$:

$$\left|\frac{1}{1}\right|<\frac{1}{\epsilon}<\epsilon$$

Did I get it right?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Maybe it is faster to notice that since $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ over $(0,\pi/2)$, your function can be written as $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)$. We just need to prove that $\tan(x/2)$ is UC over $[0,\pi/2]$, that is quite trivial since such a function is continuous over a closed interval.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great tip. I'll try. However I think it is a good practice for me to prove it the "hard way"?

Comment: I have not checked.  You will be better off by a lot if you multiply top and bottom by $1+\sin x$. We get $\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}$ and everything is easy.

Comment: Your $\mid \sin x \mid \leq 1$ argument works only if you split the sum using triangle inequality. And by the way: Your $\delta$ depends on some $x_1$, which sould not be the case. $\delta$ may only depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Andre can you please explain why? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Andre I see. So how can I improve my final move? I understand what you're saying about $|sin x| \le 1$, but let's assume if was true.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just show both $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-} f(x)$ exist. That implies $f$ extends to be continuous on $[0,\pi/2],$ hence the extension is uniformly continuous there.

Comment: When limit tends to π/2 , the function will be infinite right as cos π/2 is 0.

Comment: @Zephyr But $1-\sin x$ is also $0$ at $\pi/2.$ Just use L'Hopital to see the limit of the expression is $0$ at $\pi/2.$

Comment: Damn, so silly of me.

Comment: Can you help me with this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2375930/403592

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$  (there are much easier ways).

Multiply top and bottom by $1+\sin x$. We get $\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}$.

We want to make $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon$. We have
$$f(x)-f(y)=\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}-\frac{\cos y}{1+\sin y}=\frac{\cos x+\cos x\sin y-\cos y-\sin x\cos y}{(1+\sin x)(1+\sin y)}.$$

This has absolute value less than the absolute value of the numerator. So we want to bound
$$|\cos x+\cos x\sin y-\cos y-\sin x\cos y|,$$
which is less than or equal to
$$|\cos x-\cos y|+|\sin(x-y)|.$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I might made one more step: since $1< 1+sin x < 2 $ when $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, I can get rid of the denmerator? Then I'm left with $|cos x - cos y|$?

Comment: We have to deal with the "mixed" terms, which I simplified.

Comment: Yes. Then I'm left with $|\cos x - \cos y|$. Is it legit?

Comment: I gave up on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. I'm proving that $\frac {cosx}{1+sinx} $is continuous, and that the one sided limits exist (they are 1 and 0). And there it is proven.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is by showing it can be extended to a continuous function on the closed interval $[0,\pi/2]$, which is easy from the original form and obvious from the $\cos x/(1+\sin x)$ form.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the lipschitz condition so you just to need to prove that the derivative of f is bounded given interval.

If you differentiate f, its derivative turns out to be $\frac{-1}{1+sin(x)}$ ( if i didn't make mistakes) which is surely bounded in the given interval!

Comment: Hi, didn't study that yet.

Comment: Oh,it's not too hard. If the absolute value of the derivative of f is bounded in an open interval, then f is uniformly continuous. You can prove it with the mean value theorem quite easily.

Comment: I understand, but the term "derivative" is not in my syllabus yet (I will study it only in two weeks), so I can't use it.

Comment: Oh i see. But After you study the derivative, the lipschitz test will be often very convenient, especially when you deal with the trig. functions...you might want to use it when the time comes...