# Addition / subtraction of continuous function.

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose we have a function f(y) which is continuous over [0,2].

Can we say that f(y) - f(y+1) and f(y) + f(2-y) will also be continuous over the same range [0,2] ?

It is given that f(0) = f(2) = -1 and f(1) = 1

My thought :-

I think if f(y) is continuos, then f(y+1) will also be continuous over the range [-1,1] as we are just shifting the graph by one to the left .
So as f(y) is continuos over [0,2] and f(y+1) is continuos over [-1,1], f(y) - f(y+1) will be continuos over [0,1] as it's common range. Am I correct?

Comment: On what interval is the function $g(x):= f(x+1)$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f(y) - f(y+1)$ is not necessarily even defined on $[0,2]$.  $f$ would need to be defined on $[0,3]$.  It will be continuous on $[0,1]$.

Consider $f(y) = \frac{1}{y - 2.5}$

Comment: f(0) is not -1 in your case.

Comment: I think if f(y) is continuos then f(y+1) will also be continuous over the range [-1,1] as we are shifting the graph by one to the left .

Comment: I did not spot the boundary conditions, did you add them later?  Anyway, that is not the important point.  It was that $f(y+1)$ is not necessarily on $[0,2]$.  With your extra comments on the common range of $[0,1]$, it will be continuous.

Comment: f(2-y) will be continuos over the range [2,4] right ? So f(y) and f(2-y) don't have any common range and hence f(y) - f(2-y) is not continuos over [0,2). It will be continuos only at x=2.  Is my approach correct?

Comment: Yes, if you are careful with the ranges then you are okay.